# laravel 9 + lando = no livereload and no sourceMapping

Tags: vite, laravel-9, lando

I just create a new `Laravel 9` project and I'm using `lando`.

I have followed instructions from this : https://sinnbeck.dev/posts/getting-vite-and-laravel-to-work-with-lando

Currently, the site is working, I can update php, css or js code.

But, there is no livereloading and I've got an error in my console about a missing sourcemapping for the css at `http://localhost:3009/resources/css/app.css.map`

There is a link to the project : https://github.com/CrunchyArtie/warene-next

There is my `vite.config.js` file:

```javascript
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        https: false,
        host: true,
        port: 3009,
        hmr: {host: 'localhost', protocol: 'ws'},
    },

});
```

and my `.lando.yml` file :

```yaml
name: warene
recipe: laravel
config:
  webroot: ./public
  php: '8.1'
  xdebug: true
services:
  node:
    type: node:16
    scanner: false
    ports:
      - 3009:3009
    build:
      - npm install
tooling:
  dev:
    service: node
    cmd: npm run dev
  build:
    service: node
    cmd: npm run build
```

EDIT :

With this `vite.config.js` the livereloading works :

```javascript
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        https: false,
        host: true,
        strictPort: true,
        port: 3009,
        hmr: {host: 'localhost', protocol: 'ws'},
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- With `css.devSourcemap: true` a sourcemap file is generated and used.
- With `server.watch.usePolling: true` vite will detect file changed inside lando environment.

This is my is my `vite.config.js` file:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    css: {
        devSourcemap: true,
    },
    server: {
        https: false,
        host: true,
        strictPort: true,
        port: 3009,
        hmr: {host: 'localhost', protocol: 'ws'},
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        }
    },
});
```